# How can I join a user_id field with a comma-separated list of participant_usre_id_list in another table using Snowflake?

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, self-join

I am trying to join user_id and participant_user_id_list columns as well as looking to only have those accounts in the output that participated with each other i.e. if there is a primary user user_id 111 participating with secondary users 222, 333 and 444, then there should be at least one other entry in the table where one of the secondary users is primary (user_id) and 111 in the secondary user list. In other words, I am looking for a-b and b-a entries from the table.

The output should give me 111, 222, 444 preferably as separate rows.

[image]

Comment: can you show the desired output. Your description is rather vague.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim as mentioned in my post, the output should be 111, 222, 444 in separate rows.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I just realized the output should be three rows based on my example screenshot above - 111, 222, 444

Answer (score 1):

if you are want a bi direction match then you can use:

```
with data as (
    select column1 as user_id
        ,parse_json(column2) as participant_user_id_list
    from values
    (111,'[222,333,444]'),
    (444,'[111,333,666,777]'),
    (222,'[111,333,444]'),
    (888,'[111,444,555,666]'),
    (333,'[777,888,999]')
), flat as (
    select user_id as a
        ,f.value as b
    from data, table(flatten(input=>participant_user_id_list)) f
)
select a.a as user_id
    ,array_agg(a.b) within group (order by a.b) as co_participant
from flat as a
join flat as b
    on a.a = b.b and a.b = b.a
group by 1
order by 1
;
```

| USER_ID | CO_PARTICIPANT |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | [ 222, 444 ] |
| 222 | [ 111 ] |
| 444 | [ 111 ] |

Comment: Thanks @Simeon Pilgrim. The data that I have doesn't have opening and closing square brackets. It's just a comma-separated list as shown in the screenshot. Do you have a way around that?

Comment: This worked, but I ended up using SPLIT_TO_TABLE function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Super glad to hear you found a work-around the gap in the answer.